# Qt makefile error

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, makefile

I have been asking many questions regarding error:

```
    17:50:49: Running steps for project untitled...
            17:50:49: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
            17:50:49: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
                C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
                cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\damyant\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.4788.0.jom
            jom: D:\Qt_Pro\untitled\Makefile.Debug [debug\main.obj] Error 2
            jom: D:\Qt_Pro\untitled\Makefile [debug] Error 2
            17:50:50: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
            Error while building/deploying project untitled (kit: my kit)
            When executing step 'Make'
```

But I couldn't get any answer that can help me,here is my makefile in case it contains some error,please rectify:

```
#############################################################################
# Makefile for building: untitled
# Generated by qmake (3.0) (Qt 5.0.2) on: Mon Jun 24 17:43:08 2013
# Project:  ..\untitled\untitled.pro
# Template: app
# Command: C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\bin\qmake.exe -spec win32-msvc2010 CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG+=qml_debug -o Makefile ..\untitled\untitled.pro
#############################################################################

MAKEFILE      = Makefile

first: debug
install: debug-install
uninstall: debug-uninstall
QMAKE         = C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\bin\qmake.exe
DEL_FILE      = del
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= if not exist
MKDIR         = mkdir
COPY          = copy /y
COPY_FILE     = $(COPY)
COPY_DIR      = xcopy /s /q /y /i
INSTALL_FILE  = $(COPY_FILE)
INSTALL_PROGRAM = $(COPY_FILE)
INSTALL_DIR   = $(COPY_DIR)
DEL_FILE      = del
SYMLINK       = 
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = move
SUBTARGETS    =  \
        debug \
        release


debug: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug
debug-make_first: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug 
debug-all: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug all
debug-clean: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug clean
debug-distclean: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug distclean
debug-install: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug install
debug-uninstall: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug uninstall
release: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release
release-make_first: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release 
release-all: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release all
release-clean: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release clean
release-distclean: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release distclean
release-install: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release install
release-uninstall: FORCE
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release uninstall

Makefile: ..\untitled\untitled.pro C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010\qmake.conf C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\spec_pre.prf \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\common\shell-win32.conf \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\qconfig.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_axbase.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_axcontainer.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_axserver.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_bootstrap.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_clucene.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_concurrent.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_core.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_declarative.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_designer.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_designercomponents.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_gui.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_help.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_multimedia.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_multimediawidgets.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_network.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_opengl.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_platformsupport.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_printsupport.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_qml.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_qmldevtools.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_qmltest.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_qtmultimediaquicktools.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_quick.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_quickparticles.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_script.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_scripttools.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_sql.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_svg.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_testlib.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_uitools.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_v8.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_webkit.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_webkitwidgets.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_widgets.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_xml.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_xmlpatterns.pri \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\qt_functions.prf \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\qt_config.prf \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010\qmake.conf \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\spec_post.prf \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\exclusive_builds.prf \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\default_pre.prf \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\win32\default_pre.prf \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\resolve_config.prf \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\default_post.prf \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\win32\console.prf \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\qml_debug.prf \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\declarative_debug.prf \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\win32\rtti.prf \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\warn_on.prf \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\qt.prf \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\resources.prf \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\moc.prf \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\testcase_targets.prf \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\exceptions.prf \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\yacc.prf \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\lex.prf \
        ..\untitled\untitled.pro \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/msvc2010/lib/Qt5Core.prl
    $(QMAKE) -spec win32-msvc2010 CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG+=qml_debug -o Makefile ..\untitled\untitled.pro
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\spec_pre.prf:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\common\shell-win32.conf:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\qconfig.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_axbase.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_axcontainer.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_axserver.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_bootstrap.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_clucene.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_concurrent.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_core.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_declarative.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_designer.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_designercomponents.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_gui.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_help.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_multimedia.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_multimediawidgets.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_network.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_opengl.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_platformsupport.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_printsupport.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_qml.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_qmldevtools.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_qmltest.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_qtmultimediaquicktools.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_quick.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_quickparticles.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_script.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_scripttools.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_sql.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_svg.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_testlib.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_uitools.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_v8.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_webkit.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_webkitwidgets.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_widgets.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_xml.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_xmlpatterns.pri:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\qt_functions.prf:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\qt_config.prf:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010\qmake.conf:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\spec_post.prf:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\exclusive_builds.prf:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\default_pre.prf:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\win32\default_pre.prf:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\resolve_config.prf:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\default_post.prf:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\win32\console.prf:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\qml_debug.prf:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\declarative_debug.prf:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\win32\rtti.prf:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\warn_on.prf:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\qt.prf:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\resources.prf:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\moc.prf:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\testcase_targets.prf:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\exceptions.prf:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\yacc.prf:
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\lex.prf:
..\untitled\untitled.pro:
C:/Qt/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/msvc2010/lib/Qt5Core.prl:
qmake: FORCE
    @$(QMAKE) -spec win32-msvc2010 CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG+=qml_debug -o Makefile ..\untitled\untitled.pro

qmake_all: FORCE

make_first: debug-make_first release-make_first FORCE
all: debug-all release-all FORCE
clean: debug-clean release-clean FORCE
    -$(DEL_FILE) untitled.exp
    -$(DEL_FILE) untitled.ilk
    -$(DEL_FILE) vc*.pdb
    -$(DEL_FILE) vc*.idb
distclean: debug-distclean release-distclean FORCE
    -$(DEL_FILE) Makefile
    -$(DEL_FILE) untitled.pdb

debug-mocclean:
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug mocclean
release-mocclean:
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release mocclean
mocclean: debug-mocclean release-mocclean

debug-mocables:
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug mocables
release-mocables:
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release mocables
mocables: debug-mocables release-mocables

check: first
FORCE:

$(MAKEFILE).Debug: Makefile
$(MAKEFILE).Release: Makefile
```

Makefile.debug:

```
 #############################################################################
    # Makefile for building: untitled
    # Generated by qmake (3.0) (Qt 5.0.2) on: Mon Jun 24 17:43:08 2013
    # Project:  ..\untitled\untitled.pro
    # Template: app
    #############################################################################

MAKEFILE      = Makefile.Debug

####### Compiler, tools and options

CC            = cl
CXX           = cl
DEFINES       = -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB
CFLAGS        = -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -W3 $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010"
LINKER        = link
LFLAGS        = /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'"
LIBS          = /LIBPATH:C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\lib C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\lib\Qt5Cored.lib 
QMAKE         = C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\bin\qmake.exe
IDC           = idc
IDL           = midl
ZIP           = zip -r -9
DEF_FILE      = 
RES_FILE      = 
COPY          = copy /y
SED           = 
COPY_FILE     = $(COPY)
COPY_DIR      = xcopy /s /q /y /i
DEL_FILE      = del
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = move
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= if not exist
MKDIR         = mkdir
INSTALL_FILE    = $(COPY_FILE)
INSTALL_PROGRAM = $(COPY_FILE)
INSTALL_DIR     = $(COPY_DIR)

####### Output directory

OBJECTS_DIR   = debug

####### Files

SOURCES       = ..\untitled\main.cpp 
OBJECTS       = debug\main.obj

DIST          = 
QMAKE_TARGET  = untitled
DESTDIR        = debug\ #avoid trailing-slash linebreak
TARGET         = untitled.exe
DESTDIR_TARGET = debug\untitled.exe

####### Implicit rules

.SUFFIXES: .c .cpp .cc .cxx

{.}.cpp{debug\}.obj::
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -Fodebug\ @<<
    $<
<<

{.}.cc{debug\}.obj::
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -Fodebug\ @<<
    $<
<<

{.}.cxx{debug\}.obj::
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -Fodebug\ @<<
    $<
<<

{.}.c{debug\}.obj::
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -Fodebug\ @<<
    $<
<<

{..\untitled}.cpp{debug\}.obj::
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -Fodebug\ @<<
    $<
<<

{..\untitled}.cc{debug\}.obj::
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -Fodebug\ @<<
    $<
<<

{..\untitled}.cxx{debug\}.obj::
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -Fodebug\ @<<
    $<
<<

{..\untitled}.c{debug\}.obj::
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -Fodebug\ @<<
    $<
<<

####### Build rules

first: all
all: Makefile.Debug $(DESTDIR_TARGET)

$(DESTDIR_TARGET):  $(OBJECTS) 
    echo 1 /* CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID */ 24 /* RT_MANIFEST */ "debug\\untitled.exe.embed.manifest">debug\untitled.exe_manifest.rc
    if not exist $(DESTDIR_TARGET) if exist debug\untitled.exe.embed.manifest del debug\untitled.exe.embed.manifest
    if exist debug\untitled.exe.embed.manifest copy /Y debug\untitled.exe.embed.manifest debug\untitled.exe_manifest.bak
    $(LINKER) $(LFLAGS) /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:debug\untitled.exe.embed.manifest /OUT:$(DESTDIR_TARGET) @<<
$(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) 
!IF EXIST(debug\untitled.exe_manifest.res)
debug\untitled.exe_manifest.res
!ENDIF
<<
    if exist debug\untitled.exe_manifest.bak fc /b debug\untitled.exe.embed.manifest debug\untitled.exe_manifest.bak >NUL || del debug\untitled.exe_manifest.bak
    if not exist debug\untitled.exe_manifest.bak rc.exe /fodebug\untitled.exe_manifest.res debug\untitled.exe_manifest.rc
    if not exist debug\untitled.exe_manifest.bak $(LINKER) $(LFLAGS) /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:debug\untitled.exe.embed.manifest /OUT:$(DESTDIR_TARGET) @<<
$(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) debug\untitled.exe_manifest.res
<<
    if exist debug\untitled.exe_manifest.bak del debug\untitled.exe_manifest.bak

qmake: FORCE
    @$(QMAKE) -spec win32-msvc2010 CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG+=qml_debug -o Makefile.Debug ..\untitled\untitled.pro

qmake_all: FORCE

dist:
    $(ZIP) untitled.zip $(SOURCES) $(DIST) ..\untitled\untitled.pro C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\spec_pre.prf C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\common\shell-win32.conf C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\qconfig.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_axbase.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_axcontainer.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_axserver.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_bootstrap.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_clucene.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_concurrent.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_core.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_declarative.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_designer.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_designercomponents.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_gui.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_help.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_multimedia.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_multimediawidgets.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_network.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_opengl.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_platformsupport.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_printsupport.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_qml.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_qmldevtools.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_qmltest.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_qtmultimediaquicktools.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_quick.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_quickparticles.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_script.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_scripttools.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_sql.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_svg.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_testlib.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_uitools.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_v8.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_webkit.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_webkitwidgets.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_widgets.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_xml.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_xmlpatterns.pri C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\qt_functions.prf C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\qt_config.prf C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010\qmake.conf C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\spec_post.prf C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\exclusive_builds.prf C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\default_pre.prf C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\win32\default_pre.prf C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\resolve_config.prf C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\default_post.prf C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\build_pass.prf C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\win32\console.prf C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\qml_debug.prf C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\declarative_debug.prf C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\win32\rtti.prf C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\warn_on.prf C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\qt.prf C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\resources.prf C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\moc.prf C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\testcase_targets.prf C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\exceptions.prf C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\yacc.prf C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features\lex.prf ..\untitled\untitled.pro C:/Qt/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/msvc2010/lib/Qt5Cored.prl  RESOURCES HEADERS SOURCES OBJECTIVE_SOURCES YACCSOURCES YACCSOURCES LEXSOURCES 

clean: compiler_clean 
    -$(DEL_FILE) debug\main.obj
    -$(DEL_FILE) debug\untitled.exp debug\untitled.ilk vc*.pdb vc*.idb debug\untitled.exe.embed.manifest debug\untitled.exe_manifest.rc debug\untitled.exe_manifest.res

distclean: clean
    -$(DEL_FILE) debug\untitled.pdb
    -$(DEL_FILE) $(DESTDIR_TARGET)
    -$(DEL_FILE) Makefile.Debug

mocclean: compiler_moc_header_clean compiler_moc_source_clean

mocables: compiler_moc_header_make_all compiler_moc_source_make_all

check: first

compiler_rcc_make_all:
compiler_rcc_clean:
compiler_moc_header_make_all:
compiler_moc_header_clean:
compiler_moc_source_make_all:
compiler_moc_source_clean:
compiler_yacc_decl_make_all:
compiler_yacc_decl_clean:
compiler_yacc_impl_make_all:
compiler_yacc_impl_clean:
compiler_lex_make_all:
compiler_lex_clean:
compiler_clean: 



####### Compile

debug\main.obj: ..\untitled\main.cpp C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\QCoreApplication \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qcoreapplication.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qobject.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qobjectdefs.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qnamespace.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qglobal.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qconfig.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qfeatures.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qsystemdetection.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qcompilerdetection.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qprocessordetection.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qlogging.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qflags.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qtypeinfo.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qtypetraits.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qsysinfo.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qobjectdefs_impl.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qstring.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qchar.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qbytearray.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qrefcount.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qatomic.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qbasicatomic.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qatomic_bootstrap.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qgenericatomic.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qatomic_msvc.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qatomic_integrity.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qoldbasicatomic.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qatomic_vxworks.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qatomic_power.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qatomic_alpha.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qatomic_armv7.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qatomic_armv6.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qatomic_armv5.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qatomic_bfin.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qatomic_ia64.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qatomic_mips.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qatomic_s390.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qatomic_sh4a.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qatomic_sparc.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qatomic_x86.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qatomic_cxx11.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qatomic_gcc.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qatomic_unix.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qarraydata.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qstringbuilder.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qlist.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qalgorithms.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qiterator.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qcoreevent.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qscopedpointer.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qmetatype.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qvarlengtharray.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qcontainerfwd.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qisenum.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qobject_impl.h \
        C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qeventloop.h

####### Install

install:   FORCE

uninstall:   FORCE

FORCE:
```

My pro file :

QT       += core

```
QT       -= gui

TARGET = untitled
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Thankx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The makefile you shared seems correct, apart from this makefile there will be actual makefile named MakeFile.Debug or MakeFile.Release in Debug or Release folder, you need to verify that too.

For better understanding of problem can you share .pro file and complete build console output?

It seems that you are trying to build at a shadow build location, you may try in-place build and see if you get same error.

Try building some simple HelloWorld qt application at shadow build location see if you get same error.

Comment: i tried without shadow build but that also shows same erroe...i'm editing my question and adding .pro file and output.

Comment: @SatyaKumar Try building from commandline. 
open Qt Command prompt, go to location where your .pro file resides and run following
'nmake distclean' , 
'qmake' , 
'nmake'

Comment: abovesteps return: cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -O2 -MD -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\include" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\in
clude\QtCore" -I"release" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Forelease\ @C:\Users\damyant\AppData\Local\Temp\nm32A6.tmp
'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cl' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\bin\nmake.exe' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

Comment: I did as you said but it is not recognizing cl as an external/internal command.I have specified cl.exe path in path variables in project tab.

Comment: hey i copied cl.exe in bin folder of Qt where it was required but now i am getting error no 0x0000135.

Comment: If your visual studio, QtSdk installations are correct then you don't need to copy cl. Make sure you are running these from Qt Command prompt, it may be listed as 'Qt 5.0.2 64-bit for Desktop(MSVS 2010)' in start menu entry, this will have all your toolchain paths and other environment variables.

Comment: no cl.exe is not located itself.and qt command prompt is Qt 5.0.2 for desktop(MSVC2010).

Comment: @SatyaKumar Try invoking cl.exe from your Visual Studio 2010 command prompt, If it works there and not in Qt Command prompt then you might have some problems with Qt sdk installation. You may try building in VS2010 command prompt after adding environment variables QTDIR, QMAKESPEC and append PATH with path to qt tools (qmake, uic, moc ...).